# What caused Poltergeist screenshot to stop working when using Capybara 2.15.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

Previously, I had Capybara 2.5, and Poltergeist page.save_screenshot worked just fine. But, recently, I've just upgraded my Capybara to 2.15.4, and that caused Poltergeist page.save_screenshot not to work anymore. The file is not created.

Here is my feature spec:

```
feature 'create', js: true do
  before do
    visit root_path
  end

  scenario 'valid' do
    page.save_screenshot('test.png')
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  options = {
    js_errors: false,
    phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=false', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any'],
    timeout: 60,
    debug: true
  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

My current environment:

```
Ruby 2.3.3
Capybara 2.15.4
Poltergeist 1.9.0
PhantomJS 2.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've update Capybara, but not updated Poltergeist.  There was an update in Capybara 2.7 where `Capybara.save_and_open_page_path` was deprecated in favor of `Capybara.save_path` with slightly different behavior around relative paths. Update Poltergeist as well and your issue will probably go away.

Comment: Update Poltergeist to 1.16 now but my problem still occurs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the path. I've missed read the doc about changing path of the created file. Actually, the file was created, but just not saved in root directory as it used to be in Capybara 2.5. [link](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#debugging)